# YUI Compressor - compress from one directory to another

Tags: yui-compressor

I am on Win 7 and I want to compress my js/css files with YUI Compressor.

It uses *require.js* so I would like to keep the file names and folder structure same, before and after the compress.

I put the original js files into oldjs/ folder and want minified js files to be outputted into js/ folder.

Is there any way to do that?